# How to call java method from javascript code?

Tags: java, javascript, android

i am trying to call a function in a java android code from my javascript code.
i am getting the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'calculateSum'", source: http://www.abelski.com/courses/android/simple.html"
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
function calc()
{
var a = parseInt(document.myform.num_a.value,10);
var b = parseInt(document.myform.num_b.value,10);
var sum = window.ob.calculateSum(a,b);
document.myform.result.value = sum;
}
</script>

<body>
<form name="myform">
<br/>number 1: <input type="text" name="num_a"/>
<br/>number 2: <input type="text" name="num_b"/>
<br/><input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="+"/>
<br/>result: <input type="text" name="result"/>
</form>
</body>
```

java android code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CalculateObject calcObject = new CalculateObject();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.abelski.com/courses/android/simple.html");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(calcObject, "ob");
        setContentView(webView);
    }
    class CalculateObject
    {
        public int calculateSum(int numA, int numB)
        {
            return numA + numB;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try a `public` inner class. Also, add `@JavascriptInterface`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/WebKit/GeoWeb1/src/com/commonsware/android/geoweb/GeoWebOne.java

Comment: @CommonsWare inner class doesn't solve the issue. any another solution?

Comment: Adding the [@JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) annotation to the calculateSum() method should be enough.